# Object variable or With block variable not set when returning from function

Tags: vba, excel

Why am I receiving an *Object variable or With block variable not set* error with the following code:

```
Function GetConnection() As ADODB.Connection
    'Create connection to worksheet
    Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    cn.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
    cn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";" & "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"
    cn.Open
    GetConnection = cn
End Function
```

I've declared the object as 'cn', initialized it properly, and am then setting some properties and opening it, before returning it.

I get the error at the GetConnection = cn line.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If memory serves me right... you need to use the 'set' keyword when working with reference types (objects) in classic vb

ie:

```
Set GetConnection = cn
```

This applies to all assignments, not just function return statements.

Comment: Perfect, that worked, thank you! I'm a little embarrassed I couldn't figure that out on my own.